# flutter : catch js exception and continue

Tags: javascript, flutter

on flutter, I am trying to catch an JS exception and continue a method after catch, but none of my handling worked and finally method stopped counting:

```
myMethod(){

try {
  if (webController != null) {
    final hasElement =
        await webController?.evalRawJavascript("document.getElementById(\"gradient-canvas\").isConnected");
    if (hasElement) {
      await webController!.evalRawJavascript("gradientt.play()").catchError((e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());

      }).onError((e, stackTrace) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
    
      });
    }
  }
} on Error catch (e) {
  debugPrint("-------> ${e.toString()}");
  rethrow;
}

/// does not continue after error
```

}

I got this error on console:

```
<error: TypeError: obj[$toString] is not a function>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 327:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 337:28            _throw
```

because the correct js method is gradient. Play(). I changed it to throw exception.

How can I catch error and continue ?

Comment: What happens if you call it like `debugPrint("-------> ${e.toString}");`? Eventually, you can try to find the runtime type like `${e.runtimeType}` and see if the object returned actually has a `toString` method.

Comment: e.runtimetype is null but e is equal LagacyJavaScriptObject , and after rethrow the method will be interrupted @mutantkeyboard